# Regular expression that allow hyphen symbol between number and character but remove hyphen symbol between characters

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to write a regular expression that allow hyphen symbol **(-)** between number and character but remove hyphen symbol between characters and replace it with white space in a PHP string. I am beginner in regex don't know how to write regular expression for this can any one help

here what i need i have a string like this in PHP

```
$string ="Al-Abbas - Manama - 100" or
$string ="100 - Al-Abbas - Manama"
```

what i need output after regex applied must be like

```
Al Abbas Manama - 100
100 - Al Abbas Manama
```

Any other way to do this please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
$string ="Al-Abbas - Manama - 100"

$repl = preg_replace('/\d\h*-\h*(*SKIP)(*F)|-(?!\h*\d)/', ' ', $string);
```

- `\d\h*-\h*(*SKIP)(*F)` will fail the match if hyphen is coming after a digit
- `(?!\h*\d)` will fail the assertion if there is a digit next to hyphen

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tQ7oV6/3)

Comment: Thanks but i want to this work in this  way as well when number came first  299 - bandar Al-Seef

Comment: Dude i need little help can please change this expression to js as well

Comment: JS doesn't support same PCRE features, please create a new question so that you get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pure PHP:

```
$string1 ="Al-Abbas - Manama - 100";
$string2 ="100 - Al-Abbas - Manama";

function convertString($string) {
    $strArr = explode("-", $string);
    $new = '';
    foreach ($strArr AS $key => $val) {
        $val = trim($val);
        if (is_numeric($val)) {
            if ($key === 0) $new .= $val . " - ";
            else            $new .= " - " . $val;
        } else {
            $new .= " " . $val;
        }
    }
    return $new;
}

echo convertString($string1); //output: Al Abbas Manama - 100
echo convertString($string2); //output: 100 - Al Abbas Manama
```

Comment: Does it work if order get change like number came first ?